# How to use display:block properly with buttons in css?

Tags: html, css

When I use **display:block** it doesn't want to work which was working before. When I inspect it shows me strike through on **display:block**. Now the buttons are positioned on the right side of the col, I'd need them to be positioned in the middle under the image.

**html**

```
<div class="sectionLight">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="images/square.png">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btnCenter" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".square-modal-lg">Prime</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="images/fibo.png">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btnCenter" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".fibo-modal-lg">Fibo</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-fluid imgCenter" src="images/square_copy.png">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btnCenter" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".prime-modal-lg">Square</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btnCenter {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: buttons are under image, so what is the issue here? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/asq8wbf3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have included another css script that overwrites your current one.

You can try to make it `!important`. If that doesnt work, you might have to make your selector more spesific than the one currently overwriting it.

```
.btnCenter {
  display: block !important;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

You can debug this in the dev-tools. See the example image below:
[image]

In this example, primary.css is higher in the css hierarchy (meaning the file `primary.css` is included later than `stacks.css`) Therefore, it will overwrite the selector.

Comment: Now I learnt something new :) Buttons are positioned under the images in the middle of the col after using `!important`. It happened because of the another script as you said.

Comment: Using `!important` should be the last resort. Better would be to make the selector more specific.

Comment: This is what I wanted to ask in my previous comment but I forgot if using `!important` is okay or better to avoid it, so thanks for the extra info :)